# Dynamic select options in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I would like to have a dynamic select option values bind to select dropdown.

```
  <div ng-repeat="condition in conditions">

       <div class="form-group">
            <select ng-model="condition.Description" class="form-control">
                     <option value="">- Select -</option>
                     <option ng-value="{{age.Description}}" ng-repeat="age in ageConditions">{{age.Description}}</option>
            </select>

       </div>
  </div>
```

I like

```
age in ageConditions
```

to be dynamic. I also tried ng-options="dynamicOptions" but it always bind to the same list.

I want to achieve this with ng-repeat.

```
   Repeat 1: 
   <select ng-model="condition.Description" class="form-control">
           <option value="">- Select -</option>
           <option ng-value="ageCondition1">ageCondition1</option>
           <option ng-value="ageCondition2">ageCondition2</option>
   </select>
   Repeat 2:
   <select ng-model="condition.Description" class="form-control">
           <option value="">- Select -</option>
           <option ng-value="yearsCondition1">yearsCondition1</option>
           <option ng-value="yearsCondition2">yearsCondition2</option>
   </select>
```

As shown i want the option in select to be dynamic in ng-repeat.
Any idea?

Comment: still didnt get what dynamic you want... can you show some real data and then how should it be displayed, plunker

Comment: @harish, I want the options in select to be dynamic but can't get it to work in ng-repeat. The two block of select with different options displayed.

Comment: but how many repeats and whats the logic of which field being displayed when?? is it fixed to 2, if yes then why ng-repeat on select... need lots of clarity on the requirement

Comment: @harish, no it is not 2. I use 2 as an example and the options values can change too.

Comment: then whats the logic for it to change... is it index based?

Comment: @harish, yes just simple index based. I can't get the select to be dynamic in the ng-repeat. Hopefully someone has the answer

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you or not but: http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/1429/

Comment: @Starboy. that's not what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a directive that created a new scope for select.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <select ng-model="condition.Description" class="form-control">
                 <option value="">- Select -</option>
                 <option value="getValue(age, $parent.$index)" ng-repeat="age in ageConditions">               getText(age, $parent.index)</option>
        </select>
```

Please note that $parent.$index is used.
the dynamic nature van be achieved used functions which return the value based in $index.

```
       $scope.getValue = function(age, index) {
             if(index === 1) return age.Desciption else age.years;
       }


       $scope.getText = function(age, index) {
             if(index === 1) return age.Desciption else age.years;
       }
```

hope this helps

Comment: but i want the age in ageConditions in ng-repeat to be dynamic.

Comment: the condition can change depending on what is coming from the database

Comment: Given that's is a function. Logic is in your hand. Make it as dynamic as you want.

Comment: I tried calling ng-repeat="myFunction()". Angularjs throws an exception

Comment: If you see the answer carefully, where is the function written

Comment: my point is to make ng-repeat dynamic and calling in function. seems impossible

Comment: in the controller.js i can assign ageConditions = different conditions but the two 'select repeats' always bind to the same list. I can't make it dynamic. Anyone has any idea?